# df_output.iloc[:, 38:].fillna(0, inplace=True) не срабатывает

Tags: pandas, kaggle

На Kaggle пробую применить для очистки NaN и замены их на 0 для диапазона колонов dataframe с помощью:

```
df_output.iloc[:, 38:].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

*38 - это первая колонка, с которой начинается нужный мне диапазон.

Но ничего не происходит:

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте нормально присвоить результат, без `inplace=True`, ну то есть `df_output = df_output.iloc[:, 38:].fillna(0)`, а то у вас несколько операций через точку, не факт, что они не на копии выполняются. Если я правильно помню, `inplace` планируют в будущем вообще выпилить из-за того, что с ним много непоняток бывает.  Вернее, сделайте лучше fillna по всему датафрейму, а то остальные колонки отпадут так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще должно быть всё нормально, хотя `Pandas` и выдаёт предупреждение, что возможны глюки из-за того, что вы оперируете копией `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000,100))
df.iloc[:,38:] = np.NaN
print(df.isna().sum().sum())
df.iloc[:,38:].fillna(0, inplace=True) # проблемная строка
print(df.isna().sum().sum())
```

На выходе:

```
6200000
0
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4153: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Правильнее делать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000,100))
df.iloc[:,38:] = np.NaN
print(df.isna().sum().sum())
df.iloc[:,38:] = df.iloc[:,38:].fillna(0) # а вот так делать правильно
print(df.isna().sum().sum())
```

Вывод:

```
6200000
0
```

То есть если вы берёте срез от `DataFrame`, нельзя делать на нём операции `inplace`, потому что вы оперируете копией данных и может быть потом всякое непонятное.

Надо присваивать новые данные непосредственно в `df.loc[]` или `df.iloc[]` явным образом, тогда всё точно будет хорошо.

В будущих версиях `Pandas` параметр `inplace` планируют совсем убрать, лучше забудьте про него уже сейчас.

Comment: да, так сработало. И появился еще один вопрос...

df_preproc.describe() - выдает ошибку TypeError: cannot perform std with type Sparse[int64, 0]

df_preproc.info(): dtypes: Sparse[int64, 0](125), float64(2), int64(3), uint8(31)

а нормализация minmax 

    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    a = scaler.fit_transform(df_output)

    df_output = pd.DataFrame(a)

выдает ошибку: ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['Bar', 'Pub']"

Comment: хотя df.isna().sum(): 

Ranking              0.0
Price Range          0.0
Number of Reviews    0.0
sample               0.0
Rating               0.0
                    ... 
Vietnamese           0.0
Welsh                0.0
Wine Bar             0.0
Xinjiang             0.0
Yunnan               0.0
Length: 161, dtype: float64

Я попробовал применить df.iloc[:,38:] = df.iloc[:,38:].astype(int)

но это не помогло

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk Хм, что у вас за Sparse[int64, 0] такой интересно, это тип из какого пакета вообще?

Comment: да я сам удивился. Вообще работаю сейчас с ноутбуком в Kaggle.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk Ну, на Kaggle свои приколы и с ноутбуками и вообще. Я там давно не был, не в курсе какие библиотеки сейчас там в моде.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так в Kaggle Notebook:

```
df.iloc[:,38:] = np.nan_to_num(df.iloc[:,38:], nan=0)
df.iloc[:,38:] = df.iloc[:,38:].astype(int)
```

И это помогло.

Теперь df.info() выводит нормально:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 50000 entries, 0 to 49999
Columns: 161 entries, Ranking to Yunnan
dtypes: float64(2), int64(128), uint8(31)
memory usage: 51.1 MB

И можно применить

```
#MinMax Normalization

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
a = scaler.fit_transform(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```